# Integral over a Green's function due to the angle in cylindrical coordinates

Tags: integration, greens-function

Needs to calculate the result of an integrand, as

$$
I=\int^{2\pi}_{0} \frac{e^{ik\sqrt{r^2_1+r^2_2-2r_1r_2\cos\theta+(z_1-z_2)^2}}}{\sqrt{r^2_1+r^2_2-2r_1r_2\cos\theta+(z_1-z_2)^2}} \, d\theta
$$

which becomes the problem as,

$$
I=\int^{2\pi}_{0}\frac{e^{ik\sqrt{a-b\cos\theta}}}{\sqrt{a-b\cos\theta}} \, d\theta
$$

I do appreciate it if you know,

1) is there a close form or an approximate close form of this integrand?

2) If no, how can I efficiently integral it by numerical integration?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: hey, i would guess that this is a intermeditate step  in the calculation of a 3D integral in polar coordinates. would you be so nice to post the original integral? that maybe helpful